# How do I add text beneath an image in Preview?

Tags: preview, text, image-editing

I'm using Preview on OS Big Sur.  I would like to create a new image using a PNG file from my Desktop and having some text beneath it.  I opened my PNG file, selected the markup tool, and then clicked the text tool

[image]

I then dragged and dropped where I want the text area to be beneath my image

[image]

However, when I click within this box and start typing, nothing happens -- I don't see any text.  Am I using the right tool?  Is there something I should be doing differently?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the text color is the same as the background? Have you tried adding text to another image with different colors?

Comment: I included a screen shot in my question.  Even if those colors were the same, wouldn't I see a cursor blinking or something indicating where I would type?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. On Sonoma, I can't even move the text past the image's borders ("you are trying to place text outside the bounds of the picture" - Steve Chambers). You can still try to: 1) export it as pdf, 2) add a description beneath the image (in the pdf) and 3) export the pdf as a jpg or any image type. This works but the text gets a bit blurry.

Comment: The answer is here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88130/change-canvas-size-in-preview-app-without-scaling-image

Comment: @Gilby, that solution deson't work on my machine.  When I repaste the image it takes up a fraction of the canvas, and even still, putting a text box beneath it results in the same issue I was having earlier.